# "App boot timeout" when un-idling

Tags: heroku

My Heroku-hosted (ruby Sinatra) app has worked perfectly for the last month without me changing it, but today the app error'd while trying to start up after idling:

```
2013-02-08T15:44:34+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Idling
2013-02-08T15:44:38+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2013-02-08T15:44:40+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 0
2013-02-08T15:44:40+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to down
2013-02-08T15:50:50+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Unidling
2013-02-08T15:50:50+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from down to starting
2013-02-08T15:52:09+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H20 desc="App boot timeout" method=GET path=/ host=www.example.com fwd=207.110.13.98 dyno= queue= wait= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2013-02-08T15:52:05+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H20 desc="App boot timeout" method=GET path=/ host=www.example.com fwd=207.110.13.98 dyno= queue= wait= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
```

After a few more minutes of error codes, the app tried to unidle again and did so successfully. Any idea what caused this and how I could prevent it from happening again?

Answer (score 0):

The H20 error generally means that your app takes to long to boot after having been idle. There are details in [Heroku Dev Center](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/error-codes#h20-app-boot-timeout). As Dev Center suggests, you should probably check that assets are precompiled or if there are other things that might slow down app boot.